# Error upgrading Jasperreports server from 7.2 to 7.5 (keystore problem)

Tags: jasperserver

The upgrade procedure is pretty simple and well documented. I have been upgrading jasperreports server since version 4 always using the same procedure (buildomatic).

Now, in 7.5 version I get

> java.lang.RuntimeException: KeystoreManager was never initialized or
>   there are errors while instantiating the instance.
>
> Failed to instantiate
>   [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.crypto.KeystoreManager]: Please make sure
>   that `create-keystore` was executed;
>
> Error creating bean with name 'keystoreManager': Invocation of init
>   method failed;
>
> Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'keystoreManager';

The keystore is in `/root` folder, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the process mentioned in this link https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/encryption-jasperreports-server-75

*"If the JasperReports Server cannot find the keystore files - maybe because of permissions as noted above, you will get an exception on server start like:
Failed to instantiate [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.crypto.KeystoreManager]: Please make sure that `create-keystore` was executed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: KeystoreManager was never initialized or there are errors while instantiating the instance.
To fix this, you need to move the keystore files into a directory that is accessible by the user running the web app process. See Updating keystore files below."*